# How to uninstall ROS on Windows

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS on windows installation is giving an error on ros-catkin-tools. I want to uninstall and make a fresh install of ROS on windows, should i just delete the c:/opt/ros folder?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307689/how-to-uninstall-ros-on-windows/) by [drsolanki](https://answers.ros.org/users/38392/drsolanki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-11-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ojemz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4558/ojemz/) on 2019-07-12**:
Anyone figure this out yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess it is not the best way but worked for me.

```
choco uninstall ros-melodic-desktop_full
```

After this Chocolatey still said ROS is installed so I removed chocolatey too.

Then I deleted the Chocolatey Folder: (https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Uninstallation)

You can find it under C:\ProgramData\chocolatey

After this steps I followed the (http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows) introduction but started at the Chocolatey installation.

---

Originally posted by [chilicheese](https://answers.ros.org/users/43979/chilicheese/) with karma: 41 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leonardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44097/leonardo/) on 2019-07-19**:
I've uninstalled everything but there's still a lot of data in c:\opt\ros\melodic\x64. Do i delete this before re-installig or just leave it alone?

**Comment by [chilicheese](https://answers.ros.org/users/43979/chilicheese/) on 2019-07-21**:
I think you can delete it and start a new installation.

Did it work?

**Comment by [leonardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44097/leonardo/) on 2019-07-28**:
i deletes the files in c:\opt\ros\melodic\x64. and the re-install worked.